# Definition of "Degree Objective" in Personal Statement

Tags: meaning

I am writing my Personal Statement for my graduate school application right now.

Coming to the Degree Objective section, I became a little dizzy.

Does it require me to write which program degree I want to pursue? Or my goals in achieving graduate degree, like serve the community, self-fulfillment.

Can anyone explain what I should write about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your degree objective is simply the degree you wish to obtain (e.g. Ph.D. in Chemistry).

Answer (score 0):

I would write about both--which degree I wanted, and also, why I want to pursue that degree.